# Can't boot into WIndows 10 after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I changed the boot order in the BIOS. Since then when I try to boot Windows from GRUB it shows

> cannot load image

I've tried disabling secure boot and nothing changed. I tried booting from the <kbd>f9</kbd> menu and choosing Windows, but it goes directly to the GRUB menu.

I ran the boot info script and [these are the results](https://justpaste.it/6kn1d).

I've seen other posts like [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix). I tried it all and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

you may have damaged your windows partition
do you have a repair disk
if not you may want to reinstall windows but that requires a full format of the old windows partition

Comment: yep! that's it !

Comment: if you damaged you windows partition well get the install disk

Comment: BUT FIRST! if you can get a usb sata drive cable and connect your drive to another computer, you can do this in a libary, then back up the data to a flash drive, Disc, EXTERNAL hdd, or on the web.

Comment: then make a windows 10 8 8.1 or 7 install disk

Comment: i will provide some links

Comment: WINDOWS 7 https://webforpc.com/software/operating-systems/windows-7-starter-iso-free-download/ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- WINDOWS 8 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO --------------------------------------------------------------------WINDOWS 10 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO

Comment: these are all free HOWEVER TO OBTAIN ALL FEATURES YOU NEED TO BUY A PRODUCT KEY